# Can a PDF file have 0 pages defined or otherwise result in 0 as page size?

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I have a PHP script using Imagick, but there is the risk of a NAN error, should a PDF file provided by a user contain no pages or have a page with no height or no width. I am not sure if this is possible in a PDF structure. Also making a jpeg from a page number larger than the total pages will cause an error. Is it generally possible a valid PDF file wrapper is sent but without actual page content?

#### The core question: How can we count and measure pages for a proper error capture before entering the conversion from PDF to JPEG?

In the function below I assume it might be possible to have 0 height or 0 width. And use the code if($imH==0){$imH=1;} but having code based on an assumption doesn't feel right.

parts of the function were adopted from an article by umidjons: https://gist.github.com/umidjons/11037635

PHP code:

```php
function genPdfThumbnail ( $src, $targ, $size=256, $page=1 ){

    if(file_exists($src) && !is_dir($src)): // source path must be available and cannot be a directory

        if(mime_content_type($src) != 'application/pdf'){return FALSE;} // source is not a pdf file returns a failure
    
        $sepa   =   '/'; // using '/' as path separation for nfs on linux.
        $targ   =   dirname($src).$sepa.$targ;
        $size   =   intval($size); // only use as integer, default is 256
        $page   =   intval($page); // only use as integer, default is 1     
        $page--; // default page 1, must be treated as 0 hereafter
        if ($page<0){$page=0;} // we cannot have negative values

        $img    =   new Imagick($src."[$page]");
        $imH    =   $img->getImageHeight();
        $imW    =   $img->getImageWidth();

        if ($imH==0) {$imH=1;} // if the pdf page has no height use 1 instead
        if ($imW==0) {$imW=1;} // if the pdf page has no width use 1 instead
        $sizR   =   round($size*(min($imW,$imH)/max($imW,$imH))); // relative pixels of the shorter side

        $img    ->  setImageColorspace(255); // prevent image colors from inverting
        $img    ->  setImageBackgroundColor('white'); // set background color before flatten
        $img    =   $img->flattenImages(); // prevent black zones on transparency in pdf
        $img    ->  setimageformat('jpeg');

        if ($imH == $imW){$img->thumbnailimage($size,$size);} // square page 
        if ($imH < $imW) {$img->thumbnailimage($size,$sizR);} // landscape page orientation
        if ($imH > $imW) {$img->thumbnailimage($sizR,$size);} // portrait page orientation      
        if(!is_dir(dirname($targ))){mkdir(dirname($targ),0777,true);} // if not there make target directory

        $img    ->  writeimage($targ);
        $img    ->  clear();
        $img    ->  destroy();

        if(file_exists( $targ )){ return $targ; } // return the path to the new file for further processing

    endif;
    return FALSE; // source file not available or Imagick didn't create jpeg file, returns a failure

}
```

call the function e.g. like:

```php
$newthumb = genPdfThumbnail('/nfs/vsp/server/u/user/public_html/any.pdf','thumbs/any.p01.jpg',150,'01');
```

Comment: Always assume user-provided data, especially files, are invalid and malicious. Code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a PDF file is a container format that can contain pretty much anything, including (only) metadata with 0 pages. But even so, with this code it's quite possible to request a thumbnail for page 21 on a document that only contains 5 pages.

If that happens, the problem will occur on this line:

```
$img    =   new Imagick($src."[$page]");
```

This will throw an exception if the provided page does not exist. You can catch that exception and handle it however you want:

```
try {
    $img = new Imagick($src."[$page]");
} catch (ImagickException $error) {
    return false;
}
```

If you want to read the number of pages beforehand, you can try to let Imagick parse the document first:

```
$pdf = new Imagick($src);
$pages = $pdf->getNumberImages();
```

> The function name is a bit misleading, see [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getnumberimages.php#111196) in the PHP manual:
>
> *"For PDFs this function indicates the number of pages on the PDF, NOT images that might be embedded within the PDF."*

Here as well, if the PDF document is invalid in some way, this can throw an exception so you might want to catch that and handle it:

```
try {
    $pdf = new Imagick($src);
    $pages = $pdf->getNumberImages();
} catch (ImagickException $error) {
    return false;
}

if ($pages < $page) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Rick's suggestion to "except (ImagickException $error){return false;}" is a very useful addition for me that I didn't know before. However I think counting pages by first parsing it all through Imagick can cause a severe CPU-hog if the PDF file has way too many pages. Isn't there a way to read the pdf's meta data before parsing the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, the location of the metadata is not fixed. Some PDF creators put it at the beginning of the file, some put it at the end. You could read the first e.g. 100 KB of the file and look for a `/Pages` object and parse it (although the format of that object can be different depending on the PDF version). If not, try the same check in the last 100 KB of the file. But that's no guarantee, since the meta object could also be in the middle of the file. The only *reliable* way is to parse the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF needs to contain at least one page in its Page Tree so you can't have a zero page PDF that's valid.  If you had such a PDF and your PDF software read it as valid *and* reported zero pages for it, then that software would be quite misleading.

Acrobat will display a dialog with an error message in such a case if I'm recalling correctly and I'd imagine most other PDF software would similarly complain.

A PDF's Page Boundaries are defined by Rectangles which in themselves don't have a limitation I can find in the specification about not allowing zero width and/or height.  Though practically speaking it would be bizarre to have it and likely most PDF software would complain about it or trip over it.

You can certainly have a PDF page with no content, e.g. a blank 8.5x11" page is perfectly valid.  You could use that or perhaps some text/image on the page indicating your error occurred to the user if you like.

Comment: _"A PDF needs to contain at least one page in its Page Tree so you can't have a zero page PDF that's valid."_ - do you have a source or citation to where this is in any of the PDF specifications?